# FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken doesn't work

Tags: ios, facebook

I'm trying to fix new `FBSDKAccessToken`, but I still don't know how

My code:

```
if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
    NSLog(@"In");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Out");
}
```

When I'm successful logged in, `NSLog` always prints `Out`. I set `delegate`, everything from `FB`'s developer etc and still nothing.

Knows somebody why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved it by retrieving the token string. If the token string is nil then i'll allow user to login or else i'll navigate to home page.

Some thing like this.

```
NSString *tokenValue = [[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] tokenString];

if ([tokenValue length] == 0)
{

    NSLog(@"Allow user to login");
}

else
{

 NSLog(@"User is Already logged in");

}
```

Hope this helps.

Thanks.