# How to skip Facebook's permission page when logging in on a device that a user is already logged into Facebook

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication

I'm writing an iOS8 application in Swift.  I'm trying to login using Facebook and I'm using Facebook iOS SDK 4.1.  I'm not using the Facebook button.  I have my own simple button.  Clicking on the button, calls facebookLogin method that I wrote and am pasting below.  I run the app on a computer that I'm already logged in on Facebook.  For the first run it asks for the permissions and after I press OK, it logs in and everything's fine.  On the later runs, when I'm still logged in on the same computer, the application again shows the permission page, this time saying that the user already has authorized the app and gives an OK and Cancel option.  Pressing Ok, proceeds with the login.  I'm attaching the screenshot below.  My problem is that I don't want to get the permission page on these later runs.  I assume that it should silently proceed without bouncing to the Facebook app/website.  Trying it on the phone has similar behavior.  It doesn't show the permission page, but the bouncing to the Facebook app occurs and it comes back almost immediately.

```
let fbLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()

func facebookLogin() {

    var token = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()
    if (token != nil) {
        return
    }

    fbLoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(["public_profile"], handler: { (result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if ((error) != nil) {
            // Process error
        } else if (result.isCancelled) {
            // Handle cancellations
        } else {
            if (result.grantedPermissions.contains("public_profile"))  {
                // Handle the result
            }
        }
    })
}
```

And here's the relevant section in AppDelegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {

    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
```

I would appreciate your help.  I've seen numerous posts on this subject but not much help, specifically on the new Facebook SDK.  Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Swift, but are you calling this correctly? 

`return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];`

Comment: Thanks!  Your comment is actually the solution to my problem.  I hadn't overridden application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.  I had discussed this problem in another thread and @VijayMasiwal helped me to find the exact solution you mentioned here.  Here's the link to that thread [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30042905/what-is-the-expected-behaviour-of-facebook-login].

Comment: Good to hear this is solved for you! I will put this in a real answer, so that you can accept that. That way, if other people find this question, they can quickly see what the solution was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(This was originally a comment by me, but it turned out to be the solution as well)

You need to ensure that you are calling (the Swift equivalent of) the following:

```
return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] 
         application:application 
         didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
```

This is needed for the SDK to initiate properly. This is documented here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSDKApplicationDelegate/#instance_methods

> Call this method from the [UIApplicationDelegate
>   application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] method of the AppDelegate
>   for your app. It should be invoked for the proper use of the Facebook
>   SDK.

Answer (score 1):

You should check for a valid `FBSDKAccessToken` before calling `logInWithReadPermissions`.

```
if FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken != nil
{
  // already logged in with the requested permissions
}
else
{
  // login here
}
```

Keep in mind that if you decide to ask for some new permissions, you should probably check for those permissions specifically by checking the `permissions` property (`NSSet`) of the access token rather than just checking for the presence of a token.

Comment: I'm already checking for the token at the beginning of my method:

    var token = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()
        if (token != nil) {
            return
        }

When I restart the app, the token is nil, so it goes and calls the login.  But I think since I'm already logged in on that device, it shouldn't show me the permission page.

Comment: can you try to get the tokenString of the current access token, as such: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29914852/fbsdkaccesstoken-currentaccesstoken-doesnt-work/29974056#29974056

Comment: Are you doing hard restarts (deleting the app or killing the simulator), or the way the user would be doing it normally? The Facebook data should be saving to disk under normal conditions.

Comment: @Dima I'm doing the hard restart.  My problem is solved now.  Please see my comment above.  I should have overridden application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.  Without calling Facebook's application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method there  currentAccessToken wouldn't be loaded and would stay nil, so checking wasn't helping me.  Thanks for following up on this!

Comment: @user2732722 hi. I encountered nil (with currentAccessToken)everytime i check if user has logged in when I killed my app. FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application,openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation) seems to function as the one that transfer it to the other page, may I know what checking you do to see if user logged in already?

Comment: Make sure to return this in your application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions as the answer above says:

return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

The way I check if the user is logged in is by checking FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().  If it returns nil the user isn't logged in, otherwise the user is logged in.  If you don't implement your application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions properly you'll get nil from your currentAccessToken, when you kill the app and come back.