# What is the expected behaviour of Facebook login?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-login

I want to know what the expected behaviour of Facebook login integrated in an iPhone app is, when a user is already logged into Facebook on the device through Facebook app, and the app is granted the required permissions in the previous login.  I want to know if the app exits and starts again, should it still switch to Facebook app/website to check the permissions or should it silently log the user in without getting out of the app?  Currently, my app switches to Facebook, detects that the user has already granted access, asks for an Ok or Cancel and comes back to the app.  I wan to know if this behaviour is expected, because it seems it's doing nothing but unnecessary switching.  I have asked this question in another form and I have included my code.  Here's the link: http://bit.ly/1E1u2VI

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It silently log the user in without getting out of the app. For that you can check the current user's permissions.

This might help you:

Controlling Login dialogs

The Facebook SDK automatically selects the optimal login dialog flow based on the account settings and capabilities of a person's device. This is the default sequence that the Facebook SDK implements:

1. Facebook App Native Login Dialog
2. Facebook App Web Login Dialog
3. Mobile Safari Login Dialog
4. If the Facebook account is not set up, the Facebook SDK checks to see if the Facebook app is installed on the device. If the Facebook app is installed, the Facebook app native login dialog is presented if it's supported. If the Facebook app native login dialog can't be displayed because there's an old version of the app, the Facebook app web login dialog is presented. If the Facebook app isn't installed, mobile Safari is launched to display the Mobile Safari login dialog.

Here are the screenshots of code

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nice Reply!  So you say it should be silent.  Please refer to the link above to see my code.  After I restart the app, I check for the currentAccessToken which is nil so I call logInWithReadPermissions which I expect to use native login behavior and in this case you're saying it should be silent.  However, it goes out of my app.  How can I debug the Facebook code by turning on the logs so that I know what behavior it chooses?  In FBSDKLoginManager code there's a log statement when the native behavior fails and falls through the browser behavior.  I don't see any FB logs in my app now.  Thanks!

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you so much!  This solved my problem.  The solution was in the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.  I didn't have the call to Facebooks application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.  I added it and the login worked silently.  So, it is this method that loads currentAccessToken when the app starts.  Without this change my currentAccessToken was nil at the startup so my code was calling the login method that caused going out of the application.  Facebook didn't mention this in their documentation!  Thanks Vijay!

Answer (score 3):

I have checked the login process using safari browser it's work for me. [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] is working fine. I am attaching some screenshots might help you.

[image: AppDelegate Class]

[image: Login Button action]

[image: Check user already logged in]

Comment: Excellent! Thanks. The solution was in this call:    [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];

Comment: I call this " [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];" Thanks YvesJusot save my life.:)