# FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken is not being updated after log in

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I implemented a Facebook login button which works perfectly fine. However, after user successfully logs in into Facebook and goes back to the app, `[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]` returns `NO`. I added an observer to see if the code I want is running after returning back to the app:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self   selector:@selector(checkLogIn)name :UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
}
-(void)checkLogIn
 {
         NSLog(@"IN CHECK LOG IN");

        if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {

            NSLog(@"Access Token Activated");

        }
 }
```

And after Log In when I return to the app the `checkLogIn` method is being called but `[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]` still returns `NO`.
However, it changes to YES after I press home button on iPhone and go back to the app.

How can it be updated immediately, so I can show user another view controller?

**UPDATE:**
I found out the way to execute proper code after getting back to the app. The key is to use `FBSDKAccessTokenDidChangeNotification` is Notification Center. So final result will be like this:

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(checkLogIn) name: FBSDKAccessTokenDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

That way token will be updated and it will work.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Please check your appDelegate class and implement all the required methods of FB SDK. I am attaching a screenshot for the same.

[image]

Comment: @smartTree You can also check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30042905/what-is-the-expected-behaviour-of-facebook-login/30046216#30046216

Comment: I have all these code implemented in the app delegate. Still same problem.

Comment: so according to your screenshot @Vijay: [FBSDKProfile enableUpdatesOnAccessTokenChange:YES]; should be there?

Comment: @cashmash see the updated question where it mentioned how you can use notification in order to check the acess token.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the following code to listen for FB access token changes, rather than listening in the delegate methods:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didUpdateFacebookAccessToken) name: FBSDKAccessTokenDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```