# Facebook iOS SDK FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() is nil even when logged in?

Tags: ios, facebook, swift

I am getting some strange behavior with the FBSDKAccessToken:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    println(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()) //prints nil

    if (FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil)
    {
        // User is already logged in, do work such as go to next view controller.
        println("this never prints")
        self.generateAPILoginDetails()
    }
    else
    {
        let loginView : FBSDKLoginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
        self.view.addSubview(loginView)
        loginView.center = self.view.center
        loginView.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]
        loginView.delegate = self
        FBSDKProfile.enableUpdatesOnAccessTokenChange(true)
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "onProfileUpdated:", name:FBSDKProfileDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
    }


}
```

I am trying to get the token, but it's always nil, even when the loginView button shows the "Log Out" message, indicating that the user is, indeed, logged into Facebook.

Comment: It's really strange... are you able to see login with Facebook page?? Did you set app ID in .plist??

Comment: Yes -- appID is set.  I followed this tutorial:http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-how-to-use-login-in-facebook-sdk-4-0-for-swift/ to the letter.

Comment: check this answer- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30205396/fbsdkaccesstoken-currentaccesstoken-is-not-being-updated-after-log-in/30206661#30206661

Answer (score 8):

I figured it out:

You need to add:

```
 NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "onTokenUpdated:", name:FBSDKAccessTokenDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
```

I had the wrong NSNotification name (FBSDKProfileDidChangeNotification).

Then you use your callback handler to get the token and do stuff with it!

See here for more info: http://www.andrewkouri.com/swift-1-2-and-facebooks-new-login-sdk/

Comment: The callback works but it still doesn't solve the current access token being nil when called in viewDidLoad(). Seeing as the official FBK documentation says to use this, I'm still confused as to how to get it to work...