# Refresh FBSDKLoginButton

Tags: ios, facebook

I have implemented Facebook integration in my ios application. For that, i have integrated `FBSDKLoginButton` in the app for login via safari. It is working fine. Also there is a share button. I have used the following code for a fb share button click.

```
-(void)shareForFB
{
    FBSDKShareDialog *shareDialog = [[FBSDKShareDialog alloc] init];

    if ([shareDialog canShow])
    {
        FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
        content.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"<some url>"];

        shareDialog.shareContent = content;

        shareDialog.fromViewController = self;
        shareDialog.delegate = self;
        [shareDialog show];
    }

}
```

This is also working fine.

If i'm not logged in for FB in app via safari, i'm trying to share the message. It is opening safari, then shares the message after login.

On redirecting to app, `FBSDKLoginButton` not getting updated. It is still displaying like 'Not Logged In' case. I want to update the Login Button accordingly.

Please help

Comment: Have you implemented all the required SDK methods on your `AppDelegate.m` class? Check this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30205396/fbsdkaccesstoken-currentaccesstoken-is-not-being-updated-after-log-in/30206661#30206661

Comment: Except  [FBSDKProfile enableUpdatesOnAccessTokenChange:YES];, all i have implemented. Is that required??

Comment: This required only if you want to update user's profile.

Comment: I tried with that also. Not able to solve my issue :)

Comment: As per the Facebook - It tracks the person's login state and automatically displays the appropriate message, Log in or Log out. Are you sure that you are properly logged in to the FB? You can check login state using function `[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] `. If this return nil that means you are not log in.

Comment: It is returning nil. Actually i want to login first and then share on SHARE button click. Everything is happening except app is not getting logged in. Can i force login for that ??

Comment: User required to be logged in before sharing anything.