# Issues Using Facebook SDK for iOS (no reaction of "Confirm" button and "Safari cannot open")

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook-sdk-4.0

Facebook SDK is so buggy for iPhone. Started from the bug discussed here: [Facebook iOS8 SDK build module error for FBSDKCoreKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29435377/facebook-ios8-sdk-build-module-error-for-fbsdkcorekit) Finally I solved it in an interesting way: the key was that I needed refer to the SDK where I installed it rather than copying the SDK into my app. Plus the FacebookAppID for every app should be unique, otherwise, the issues related to the linkers occur.

Anyway, when I run my FB app using XCode Simulator, I got the login page, and after it, I am directed to the window "You have already authorized MyAppName". The above button "Confirm" does not work at all, and, if I press another buttons like "OK" or "Cancel", I got the error: "Safari cannot open the page because the address is invalid". It looks that the address in the safari address field is like "https://m.facebook.com/v2.3/dialog/oauth/confirm"

My version of iOS: 8.1. XCode Version: 6.1. The app is simulated for iPhone 6.

Comment: I do not know how but finally I got it worked. However, the last attempt was like copy-paste "URL types" and "URL Schemes" keywords from facebook page to pList. In the case I typed them  before it did not work. Btw, I typed them without errors. So, it started to work because of the strange actions like copy-paste, still cannot explain.

Comment: This problem may be because of the SDK methods are not properly implemented. Check this answer may it help you to understand the flow or the required methods of FB SDK- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30042905/what-is-the-expected-behaviour-of-facebook-login/30046216#30046216